# left justification output to a flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written this query(sql 2008) and for some reason once uploaded to a flat file and I cant get it to left justified. It's a 10 character length entry and should start 5 spaces from its current starting place on a notepad for instance.

```
REPLICATE(' ',10-LEN(
    ISNULL(
        CASE WHEN LTRIM(REPLACE(A.DIAGN1, '.','')) =''
            THEN NULL
            ELSE LTRIM(REPLACE(A.DIAGN1, '.',''))
        END
    , 'V689')
))+ISNULL(
        CASE WHEN LTRIM(REPLACE(A.DIAGN1, '.','')) =''
            THEN NULL
            ELSE LTRIM(REPLACE(A.DIAGN1, '.',''))
        END
    , 'V689') AS PRIME_DIAGN_CODE, --ISNULL(LEFT(' '+REPLACE(A.DIAGN1, '.',''), 10), LEFT(''+'V689',10))     -- Primary Diagnosis Code (10)
```

Thanking you in advance,
Khan

Comment: You might want to cast the columns as CHAR. If it's varchar it will remove leading blanks.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem... what happens to this formatted output between when it is generated and when you open the text file?

Comment: the result are right justified instead of LEFT.

Answer (score 0):

here is a 10 character length entry, but I dont understand what you mean by "should start 5 spaces from its current starting place" if you want it left aligned...do you want it left aligned but indented 5 spaces?

Below is the script to get the 10 character string... I have used underscores so it will be easy to see where the spaces would be... obviously you would need to replace the underscore with a space in the script.

Hope this helps - just let me know if I have misunderstood. BTW, you need to @Username mention us otherwise we don't know you have provided more info... lucky I checked.

```
declare @DIAGN1 varchar(10) = '1234'

select
    Right(REPLICATE('_',10) + ISNULL(LTRIM(REPLACE(@DIAGN1, '.','')),'V689'),10) as RightJust_PRIME_DIAGN_CODE,
    left(ISNULL(LTRIM(REPLACE(@DIAGN1, '.','')),'V689') + REPLICATE('_',10),10)  as LeftJust_PRIME_DIAGN_CODE
```